# prefpane not giving option to install for single user

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspreferencepane

I have a mac os preference pane that i'm developing at the moment and I'm finding it's behaving differently to what i'm used to when it comes to installing. When I double click on it to install it instead of receiving the option to install it for this user or all users I am just asked whether I would like to install it and this is performed for all users. Something else i've noticed is when I then double click on it again to reinstall instead of being given the standard prompt to replace I receive an error saying that the prefpane is installed with Mac OS X and can't be replaced. It seems like it might be getting incorrectly identified somehow or maybe i've set something incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe i've worked this one out. Thought i'd post it here incase anyone has issues in the future. This was occurring because my bundle identifier for the prefPane was com.apple.prefpane. This must cause OS X to think its an OS level prefpane and handle the installation differently. Anyways, hope this saves someone some time in the future.